# Android - Performing searches with AsyncTask, sometimes causes java.lang.IllegalStateException (conn# 0) already closed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, searchview, android-cursor

I have implemented an app that has activity which uses a `searchview` in its `actionbar`.

The thing is that while developing and testing on modern devices (android 4.4) I never had any problem, but now that I have tested the app in some devices with android 3.0 or android 4.0 the app sometimes crashes while searching and gives me this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(457): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.ss.quicorder/databases/QuickOrder.db (conn# 0) already closed
11-25 11:44:37.864: E/AndroidRuntime(457):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2117)
```

This is the code I use to search:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                if (!query.isEmpty() && query.trim().length()>0) { 
                    displayResults(query);
                }
                else{                   
                    mResultsListView.setAdapter(null);
                }
                return false;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

        });
```

The **displayResults** function only executes an AsyncTask:

```
    private void displayResults(String query) {
        new sSearchCustomers().execute(query);
    }
```

The **AsyncTask** the queries the database:

```
class SearchCustomers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(String... params) {
            // get the query
            String stringToDisplay = params[0].toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            String stringToSearch = Normalizer.normalize(stringToDisplay,
                    Normalizer.Form.NFC);
            Cursor resultados = SearchCustomersActivity.this.mDB
                    .searchCustomersByName((stringToSearch != null ? stringToSearch
                            : "@@@@"));
            return resultados;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {           
            if (result != null) {               
                String[] from = new String[] {  
                        QuickOrderDB.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                        QuickOrderDB.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS };

                int[] to = new int[] { 
                        R.id.nameTextView,
                        R.id.addressTextView};

                SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        SearchCustomersActivity.this,
                        R.layout.customer_results_item, result, from, to,0);
                mResultsListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);             

            }
        }

    }
```

And this the code for **searchCustomersByName** :

```
   public Cursor searchCustomersByName (String name {
        String where = CUSTOMER_NAME_NORM + " LIKE ? ";
        String[] whereArgs = { "%" + descripcion + "%"};

        this.openReadableDB();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(CUSTOMER_TABLE, null, where, whereArgs, null,
                null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        this.closeDB();
        return cursor;

    }
```

As you can see in the code for **searchCustomersByName** , every time I return a `Cursor` I close the database, but I'm not sure if executing an `AsyncTask` for every single letter the user types in is what it's causing this, I mean, **is there any chance that one AsyncTask closes the database while another is performing a query**. **Aren't they supposed to be executed sequentially**?? Also the fact of never being able to close the cursor really worries me.

As always, any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.